# unicode and str are the same in python3?(jupyter notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, jupyter-notebook

according to official document, all str in python3 are in unicode, and actually there in no 'unicode' type in python3.

But there is a strange thing happened when I run jupyter notebook

```
time = re.findall(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', rating_bar.find('span', class_='rating-qualifier').text)[0].split('/')

di['date'] = '/'.join([str.zfill(t,2) for t in time[:2]] + time[2:] )
```

where rating_bar is a Beautiful Soup node, and jupyter notebook give this error

```
<ipython-input-9-a5ac4904b840> in parse_page(html)
     25                                                           class_='rating-qualifier').text)[
     26             0].split('/')
---> 27         di['date'] = '/'.join([str.zfill(t,2) for t in time[:2]] + time[2:] )
     28         di['rating'] = float(
     29             rating_bar.find('div', class_='i-stars')['title'].split()[0])

TypeError: descriptor 'zfill' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

it's weird because there is no 'unicode' type in python3. And actually this code run correctly in my terminal.

Comment: That sounds like you installed something weird with its own `unicode` type. Maybe python-future?

Comment: Or, of course, maybe you're not on Python 3.

Comment: Why don't you write `t.zfill(2)`?